# Mouse Wheel within jquery .animate

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have created some JavaScript to scroll up and down my DIV which has a overflow.   I already have an up and down button that works fine with this code, I want to know how I can also add the mouse-wheel to scroll, below is  my code:

```
var t = 0;

function MoveUp() {
    t += 665;
    if (t > 0) t = 0;
    $("#contents ").animate({
        top: t
    }, 1000, function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
}

function MoveDown() {
    t -= 665;
    with($("#contents")) {
        //if(t < -clientHeight)
        //t = -clientHeight;
        if (t < -1330) t = -1330;
        $("#contents").animate({
            top: t
        }, 1000, function () {
            // Animation completed

        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please give some description , your question is not clear, or you can create a fiddle example.

Comment: All i want to do is be able to scroll down my div by using the mouse wheel?

Comment: Is there a reason you are using JavaScript to complete the scroll? HTML elements automatically scroll if they are bigger than their parents. This is seen by overflow:auto on css which is the default value for all elements. Or can be explicitly set using overflow:scroll; (But the scrollbars always will be visible.

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS to enable scrolling on your page:

```
body{overflow:scroll;}
```

OR

Scroll for a specific div:

```
.yourDivClass{overflow:scroll;}
```